# Compare-Object is returning the wrong value

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I'm working on a PowerShell script and the `Compare-Object` cmdlet is not returning what I expect. I won't put the whole script here, but this is the general idea:

```
$knownFiles = Import-Csv -Path "C:\knownfiles.csv"
$currentFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\file\share"
$knownFileObject = $knownFiles |
                   Select-Object -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUTC |
                   Sort-Object -Property Name
$currentFileObject = $currentFiles |
                     Select-Object -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUTC |
                     Sort-Object -Property Name
```

So now, I have two sorted PSCustomObjects containing the Names, Length and Last Write Time of a set of files. Here's what I can't figure out.

If the objects are identical, `Compare-Object` returns nothing, as expected. However, using the example below:

`$knownFileObject` looks like this:

```
Name          Length     LastWriteTimeUtc
----          ------     ----------------
file1.dat     38988     1/1/2018 8:04:57 AM
file2.dat     7182      1/2/2017 8:03:24 AM
file4.dat     1026      1/3/2017 8:04:20 AM
file5.dat     25137     1/3/2018 8:07:51 AM
```

`$currentFileObject` looks like this:

```
Name          Length     LastWriteTimeUtc
----          ------     ----------------
file1.dat     38988     1/1/2018 8:04:57 AM
file2.dat     7182      1/2/2017 8:03:24 AM
file3.dat     1026      1/2/2018 8:04:30 AM
file4.dat     1026      1/3/2017 8:04:20 AM
file5.dat     25137     1/3/2018 8:07:51 AM
```

If I run

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $knownFileObject -DifferenceObject $currentFileObject
```

it will return this:

```
InputObject                                                            SideIndicator
-----------                                                            -------------
@{Name=file5.dat; Length=25137; LastWriteTimeUtc=1/3/2018 8:07:51 AM}  =>
```

It definitely detects that there is a difference between the two objects, but it always just returns the last row, instead of the actual record that's different. If there are two changed files, it returns the last two rows. If I add a `"-property Name"` to the `Compare-Object`, it returns the correct file name, but I also need to look for differences in size and write time. I can use `Export-Csv` to write both of the objects back out to a file, then run `Compare-Object` on the `Get-Content` of those files, and that works great, but I don't want to have to write two files to disk, as this job will be running hundreds of times per minute on different folders.

**EDIT:** Per one of the suggestions, I've also tried `Compare-Object ... -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUtc`, and when I do that, it returns every item in both objects, or a 100% mismatch.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the properties by which you want to compare the objects:

```
Compare-Object $knownFileObject $currentFileObject -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUtc
```

You also need to ensure that you're comparing the same thing. The problem with your approach is that the `LastWriteTimeUtc` property of `FileInfo` objects is a `DateTime` object, which has sub-second precision:

```
PS C:\> Get-Date| Format-List *

DisplayHint : DateTime
DateTime    : Donnerstag, 25. Januar 2018 16:31:07
Date        : 25.01.2018 00:00:00
Day         : 25
DayOfWeek   : Thursday
DayOfYear   : 25
Hour        : 16
Kind        : Local
Millisecond : 268          ← this here
Minute      : 31
Month       : 1
Second      : 7
Ticks       : 636524946672682859
TimeOfDay   : 16:31:07.2682859
Year        : 2018
```

but the timestamps from your CSV are strings with a precision limited to seconds, thus there'll likely be a miniscule difference between original and stored timestamp.

In your case the best approach would be to store the timestamp in a defined format (long ISO format for instance) and use the same format for the timestamp from the directory listing. Sorting the arrays isn't required, BTW, so you can drop that step.

```
$saved   = Import-Csv 'C:\knownfiles.csv' |
           Select-Object Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUtc
$current = Get-ChildItem '\\server\share' |
           Select-Object Name, Length,
               @{n='LastWriteTimeUtc';e={$_.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString('s')}}

Compare-Object $saved $current -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUtc
```

Comment: Note that if you move a file, `Compare-Object` won't notice it with these properties.  So if you have C:\Folder\File.txt and D:\Folder\Folder2\File.txt, `Compare-Object` above won't notice it.  You'd have to create some relative path property to compare with to detect that.  I only point it out because this has bit me on more than one occasion. I have developed a healthy aversion to `Compare-Object`.  You have to be very specific and very careful.

Comment: True, but in this case probably less relevant, because the content of a single share is compared against a reference list, and there's no recursion involved.

Comment: I specifically tried this very early on. If I specify all three properties, then it returns a 100% mismatch. In other words, for the example above, it would return 5 mismatched items. Also, if I compare just the LastWriteTimeUtc, it will also return all of the objects.

Comment: That's most likely because the `LastWriteTimeUTC` from the CSV is a *string* while the `LastWriteTimeUTC` from the directory listing is a *`DateTime`* object.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct. I actually figured it out, then came here to post my solution, but yes, the datetime in each object didn't really match, although the display was the same. When I compared "$LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks" the values were different.

Comment: I took the opposite approach that you suggested. Instead of truncating the datetime on the DifferenceObject, I expressed the datetime to 7 decimal places before writing it out to the CSV. When I import the CSV and specify datetime on that column, it imports the whole thing into the new object, which has the same number of ticks as the DifferenceObject. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Actually, you took the same approach, just picked a different date format. ;)